# Don't understand why Map returns iterator makes code to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, python-2.x

I have some code that does:

```
map(lambda increment:
                 self.__delete_table_id_range(table, delete_field, value,
                                              delete_interval, increment),
                 range(delete_interval.min, delete_interval.max, self.purge_range))
```

In `python 2` it works fine, but in `python 3` I debugged and `__delete_table_id_range` function is never called.

I know that `map` returns now an `iterator`, so I changed the `map` to become a `list` with:

```
list(map(lambda increment:
                     self.__delete_table_id_range(table, delete_field, value,
                                                  delete_interval, increment),
                     range(delete_interval.min, delete_interval.max, self.purge_range)))
```

And only adding this the `__delete_table_id_range` function runs.

I don't understand why is this happening. Can somebody explains?

Comment: The map iterator (and other iterators in python) are what's known as *[lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)*.

Comment: Because if you don't iterate over the iterator the function is never called.

Comment: You're misusing `map`. Consider using a for loop instead.

Comment: More importantly, you **shouldn't have been using `map` for side-effects *to begin with***. This should just be a for-loop

Comment: `map` was a function that returned a list in Python 2. In Python 3 it's a *type* that implements the iterator protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map method return you an iterator that you can iterate with a classic for

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
result = map(lambda index: my_list[index] * 2, range(0, len(my_list), 1))
for index, element in enumerate(result):
    print(f"Element[{index}]: {element}")
```

You can do this, but I not recommend you

```
result = map(lambda increment: self.__delete_table_id_range(table, delete_field, value, delete_interval, increment), range(delete_interval.min, delete_interval.max, self.purge_range))
for element in result:
    pass
```

In your case I think it is better a classic for

```
for index in range(delete_interval.min, delete_interval.max, self.purge_range):
    self.__delete_table_id_range(table, delete_field, value, delete_interval, increment)
```